# <script> doesn't always load when opening page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have a script that basically refreshes the time consistently so the user sees the time with the seconds/mins/h etc. adding up.

For some reason, sometimes when I load the page it works, but most of the time no. This is very unusual and I'm wondering if anyone would have an input.

For styling purposes, the em tag really needs to stay in h1.

Here's my code:

```
    <head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css">
<h1>The Trade Shack<em id="demo"></em></h1>
<title>Homepage</title>

<script>
    function getCurrentDate(){
var fullDate = new Date();
var day = fullDate.getDay();
var stringDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var month = fullDate.getMonth();
var stringMonth = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var numDay = fullDate.getDate();
var year = fullDate.getFullYear();
var hour = fullDate.getHours();
var minute = fullDate.getMinutes();
var second = fullDate.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = stringDays[day] + ", " + stringMonth[month] + " " + numDay + ", " + year + ", " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

}

setInterval(getCurrentDate,1000);
</script>

    </head>
```

Comment: wrap the code with window.onload..It should work

Comment: just call the setInterval within window.onload...it will work perfectly

Comment: dont use h1,.. in the head fragment. the head fragment should only include elements such as link, script, meta or title. everything else should be used in the body tag. you can validate your markup using https://validator.w3.org/ for example

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but you might want to look into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which makes working with dates a lot easier.

Comment: I ran it and your code worked perfectly, I don't think the problem is anything to do with you code. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/bqbcdtcp/ <head> <<< JsFiddle doesn't include the head tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `setInterval` in `window.onload`.

```
...

window.onload=function(){
    setInterval(getCurrentDate,1000);
};
```

Additionally, to fix some problems you might have with your html later, move your `<h1>` from `<head>` to `<body>`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remove the h1 element (and all inside of it) and put that on the body tag of your document, then use the `window.onload` event and that's where you're going to call this pice of code `setInterval(getCurrentDate,1000);`

You can check here for use the `window.onload`
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

I hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the function works even if 'demo' is not found. Otherwise it can cause a blocking error and prevent further execution. And put <h1> within the body rather than the head.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css"/>
<title>Homepage</title>
<script>
function getCurrentDate() {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (!demo) {return;}
  var fullDate = new Date();
  var day = fullDate.getDay();
  var stringDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  var month = fullDate.getMonth();
  var stringMonth = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var numDay = fullDate.getDate();
  var year = fullDate.getFullYear();
  var hour = fullDate.getHours();
  var minute = fullDate.getMinutes();
  var second = fullDate.getSeconds();
  demo.innerHTML = stringDays[day] + ", " + stringMonth[month] + " " + numDay + ", " + year + ", " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
}
setInterval(getCurrentDate, 1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Trade Shack<em id="demo"></em></h1>
<!--More HTML here-->
</body>
```